# Xamarin Studio can't even run Tasky simple demo app

Tags: android, xamarin

I did a fresh install of Xamarin Studio on Windows 7. Tried to run the simple Hello world Tasky app....

"Could not find android.jar for API Level 10."

Alarm bells! Here we go again...so in the Android SDK Manager I can see that API 10 SDK was indeed not installed so I tried to install from Manager but came up with the following error:-

Downloading SDK Platform Android 2.3.3, API 10, revision 2
URL not found: C:\PROGRA~2\Android\ANDROI~1\temp\android-2.3.3_r02-linux.zip (Access is denied)
Done. Nothing was installed.

MOre alarm bells...So, I had to physically give my self write access to the folder in Windows and then also the platforms folder in the android sdk folder...hard work!

So now the solution builds, but still won't run! ... the default Galaxy Nexus emulator starts but then doesn't run Tasky..... Its enough to drive you nuts man.

There seems to be a lack of robustness like checking which android API is targeted for the project against an appropriate emulator version? Thats without even mentioning the Windows file permissions!.

What do I need to do get Xamarin Studio to run the simple Tasky demo app?

Comment: Try using a more recent SDK. In the project settings, select one of the newest SDK and install it via the SDK Manager.

Comment: I agree, download the most recent SDK tools. Also make sure you don't have two JDK installed it doesn't do good to Xamarin (for example 1.7 and 1.8 together).

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you don't run the SDK Manager with elevated permissions.

Run the SDK Manager as Administrator

Answer (score 0):

I ran the API 15 Emulator and it spun up the demo app, but Xamarin Studio has crashed out a few times on Windows so probably best to use Visual Studio as you will get better Intellisense, code completion etc